# Python 'continue' interfering with 'try/except' or 'with'?

Tags: python

I have an old script doing its duty for years now, which suddenly failed, and I don't see how it can even get to the point where it fails, since I thought to have that case eliminated:

It should go through a list of files (content of a directory), and if the current file ends with `.sum`, it should check if there is a file with the same name minus the `.sum` ending (like `file1.txt.sum` and `file1.txt`).
If both files exist, it should make a checksum of file.txt` and compare it to the content of the checksum file.

Only if this check is successful, there will be further operations ending with both files getting deleted from the directory.

```
for file in filelist:
  checksum_downloaded_file, checksum_from_checksumfile = '0', '1'
  if file.endswith('.sum'):
    # read checksum from checksum file
    f_sum = open(SAVETO + file, 'rb')
    with f_sum:
      checksum_from_checksumfile = f_sum.readline().split(' ')[0].rstrip().lower()
    # checksum() the file
    try:
      f = open(SAVETO + file[:-4], 'rb')
    except:
      continue
    with f:
      checksum_downloaded_file = hashlib.sha256(f.read()).hexdigest()

    # compare delivered checksum with selfmade
    if checksum_downloaded_file == checksum_from_checksumfile:
      [...]
      sftp.remove(file)
      sftp.remove(file[:-4])
```

I thought the check if a file exitsts with the same name as the checksum file except the `.sum` ending would be done in a reliable way by the

```
    try:
      f = open(SAVETO + file[:-4], 'rb')
    except:
      continue
```

block. But today the script failed while trying to delete both files at the end of the script, because the file without `.sum` ending didn't exist. How can this happen? Doesn't `continue` do its job in that context?

EDIT:
Since it seems there is nothing logically wrong with the code, the error might lay outside (although I don't know how it could). Therefore further informations: The actual source of the files is a directory reached via SFTP (pysftp used). The `filelist` is filled by `filelist = sftp.listdir()`, and all files are downloaded (to `SAVETO`) before the problematic block starts. They should get removed on the SFTP server with `sftp.remove(file[:-4])` afterwards and this is where the script fails throwing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 71, in <module>
    sftp.remove(file[:-4])
  File "/home/alba/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 728, in remove
    self._sftp.remove(remotefile)
  File "/home/alba/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 365, in remove
    self._request(CMD_REMOVE, path)
  File "/home/alba/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 780, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/home/alba/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 832, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/home/alba/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 861, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

EDIT2: Still can't let this go. I guess if the file got deleted on the server after the script downloaded it, the script would fail like this because of course the file wouldn't be there then anymore. But the script failed every time from then on. Doesn't make sense..

EDIT3: Solved in answer. Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Could you please use consistent indentation? Preferably four spaces as requested in the [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Comment: in my script i use 2 spaces, got mixed here, will correct

Comment: I'd use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create the filepath and catch only the relevant exception. It won't solve your problem now but may help you in the future.

Comment: Any possibility there were two instances of the script running? At first glance it looks like a race.

Comment: @AdamKG good idea, indeed it runs every 10min per cron. but it didn't fail just once, but every 10min from that on...

Comment: Are you sure the failure is because the downloaded file doesnt exist, vs. not having permissions on that file or something? You didn't include the code where the deletion happens, not clear to me if you might have a similar try/except there swallowing an OSError or whatnot

Comment: at least the error message is quite clear `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` for the command where `file1.txt` should get removed; permissions shouldn't be a problem, all file have the same owner and permissions; no try/except in there

Comment: The traceback shows `sftp.remove(file[:-4])` without `SAVETO`. Wrong working directory maybe.

Comment: yes, sorry, should have explained that more. SAVETO is just a local working directory. a file should get deleted on the SFTP server after the script confirmed the integrity of the downloaded file.

Comment: I think you're going to have to cut the script down to something small that we can run and reproduce the problem if you want more specific help. Otherwise, we can only speculate.

Comment: We really should not be giving you "debugging" help here; but why not try putting some print statements in each part of your try-except and print the variables in use to help you trace/verify what is actually being passed (and maybe some identifier of the process for multiple instances)

Comment: Also, your error traceback does not line up with the code you provided.  Your code does not show `sftp.remove(file[:-4])` (which is where the error orginates, not the try-except block you are quoting with the `f = open(SAVETO + file[:-4], 'rb')`)

Comment: @SurestTexas, yes, my initial idea was wrong and now it got kind of a wide debugging scope.. should I change the title or delete the post?; the remove command was indicated as [remove files], I didn't suspect it to be the problem because (as I now will edit into the post) just before the failing remove() call there is another successful one for the checksum file. unfortunately I can't reproduce the bug since it happend around a dozen times in a row.

Comment: Post the cause and resolution of your issue as an answer and accept it tomorrow.  You get reputation for that and it will help others.  Clean up your last question edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first approach to search for the bug in the code gave the title to this thread, and it turned out to be wrong.

The bug happens when the input directory gets fed with a checksum file, which already has been fed in the past, and back then correctly, ergo with a correspondent data file, but now without that correspondent data file:
The (again) downloaded checksum file gets evaluated and the script looks for a correspondent data file, which is still present in the working directory from the past. It runs its operations and finally tries to remove the checksum and the data file from the input directory, which fails for the data file.

An unforeseen, unhandled case; out of the initial specifications, but still embarrassing. I learned from this to sort the list of debugging approaches more realistically.